# CVXPY problem takes a long time to find an optimal solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy

I have CVXPY problem defined with a volume array, and a cost array to match each of volumes. The problem has 192 variables and 3 constraints which I have defined.

My goal is to minimize the cost in this problem to deliver a specific volume.

I am not to sure where I am going wrong with defining the problem to make it take such a long time. I am using the GLPK_MI solver.

The volume array is as follows:

```
volume_ = np.array([[0, 17100] for data in [i for i in range(0, 96)]])
```

The cost array is as follows:

```
full_cost = [[0, data] for data in [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,  0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,  0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]]
```

If have defined the problem as below:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Volume and cost
full_cost = [[0, data] for data in [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,  0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45,  0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]]
cost_ = np.array(full_cost)
ex = np.array([[0, 17100] for data in [i for i in range(0, 96)]])

# Minimum volume required
v_min = 300000

# Selection variable
selection = cp.Variable(shape=ex.shape, boolean=True)

# Constraints
assignment_constraint = cp.sum(selection,axis=1) == 1

volume_= cp.sum(cp.multiply(ex,selection))
volume_constraint = volume_ >= v_min

cost_constraint = cp.sum(cp.multiply(cost_, selection))

constraints = [assignment_constraint, volume_constraint, cost_constraint]

cost_ = cp.sum(cp.multiply(cost_,selection))

# Problem definition
assign_problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost_), constraints)
assign_problem.solve(solver=cp.GLPK_MI, verbose=True)  

# Find solution in ex variable
assignments = [np.where(r==1)[0][0] for r in selection.value]
c = [ ex[i][assignments[i]] for i in range(len(assignments)) ]
best_volume = np.sum(np.multiply(ex,selection.value))
best_cost = np.sum(np.multiply(cost_,selection.value))
print(best_cost)
print(c)
```

I would welcome any input from yourselves, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check your definition of cost_constraint. As it is now it fails with ``cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.`` Also you probably want it to have some bound?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: your code returns "Problem does not follow DCP rules" error

Comment: Also your redefining of input data with cvxpy objects will cost you some errors at the end after solving. Better use new names.

Comment: Code should be updated to correct this.

Comment: Why do you have an unbounded constraint ``cost_constraint``? Not that it is wrong but suggests you maybe had something in mind but forgot to write it.

Comment: And yes GLPK seems to be stuck in some branching. There doesn't seem to be your fault in this. Try another solver. MOSEK solves the problem immediately.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Are there and solvers that you know of that would work like MOSEK and not require a license?

Comment: Try the Cplex community edition (pip install cplex). This should fit.